# Como incluir conteudo de uma pagina .py em outra pagina .py

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Como faço um `include` ou abrir uma página python em outra, por exemplo em **php**:

```
include 'content/filename.php';
```

Carregar o Html ele carrega mais o arquivo `.py` não, 
já tentei o comando `open`

```
fp = open('content/header.py')
html = fp.read()
fp.close()
```

Comment: Não sei se está claro... Você tem outro arquivo `.py`, e dentro dele quer ler código html?

Comment: sim, só que esse codigo tanbém terá codigo python

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade você nem precisava dar tanta volta como o Paulo cita acima. Você pode fazer uma função que armazena estes valores e no outro arquivo você puxa-la:

```
from arquivo1 import funcao
a,b,c = funcao()
```

Além disso você pode deixar estes valores armazenados em variáveis e puxa-los pelo outro arquivo como se fossem funções normais.

Comment: Valeu funciona tanbém!

Comment: Não é que "funciona também': esse é o jeito de se fazer as coisas. Só nao é o mais comum em PHP, por qu PHP evoluiu a partir de uma linguagem para templates de páginas. Em programação, voce usa módulos com funções  - e cada função é reutilizável